# Drawing a maze using a 2d array with the same layout

Tags: java, grid, multidimensional-array, maze

I'm creating a grid-based maze game and I'm currently using a 10 x 10 2d integer array to deal with drawing the maze and simple collision detection.

My problem, is that when drawing the grid using nested for loops, it draws it in columns and the drawn maze is flipped. For example

```
int [][] map= {
                 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
                 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
                 {2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
                 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,},
                 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,},
                 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,},
                 {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,},
                 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
                 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
                 {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}
               };

for(int i=0;i<map.length;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<map.length[0];j++){
     switch(map[i][j]){
      case 0:drawRect(i,j,width,height,blue);
       break;
      case 1:drawRect(i,j,width,height,white);
       break;
      case 2: drawRect(i,j,width,height,red);
       break;
     }
   }  
}
```

draws this

[image]

instead of

[image]

My current way of solving this is by flipping the i and j values. But is there anyway to draw the 2D array the way it is written out or even a better way of creating a grid maze that is still pretty simple?

Comment: `for(int j=0;j>map.length[0];j++){` Umm... that's not valid

Comment: This might be a situation where naming your variables in a way that represents what they refer to might make your code more understandable. So, for example, row and col instead of i and j. Then it's a lot more understandable when you see `drawRect(col,row,width,height,blue)` in the code. It doesn't feel like you're "swapping" them this way; you're using them in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to make the code more understandable was part of my problem and changing the counters does help with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's drawing your map sideways because the i / j values you have read it that way.  The loop takes the top left value and reads down as it draws, then goes in to the next column and draws down again.  Which is why flipping i / j fixes the way it's drawn.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is that you're providing row and col to `drawRect`, which takes col and row.

In your code, i is the current row and j is the current column.

However, in the Rectangle constructor: `Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)`, x is the column and y is the row.

As others advised, switch out i and j for row and col for clarity, then pass them to your `drawRect` in the proper order.